# How Can I Use Datediff in an Outlook Macro to calculate number of days left to end of month?

Tags: vba, outlook

So - writing a macro **in outlook** and I want to calculate the number of days (or work days even better) remaining in the current month. This code generates runtime error 5: invalid procedure call or argument. Thoughts?

```
Public Sub MetricsMail()
Dim MyEmail As MailItem
Dim DaysRemain As Long
Dim EndDate As Date
EndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)
DaysRemain = VBA.DateDiff(d, Now(), EndDate)

Set MyEmail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
With MyEmail
    .To = "Metrics"
    .Subject = Format(Now(), "mmmm dd, yyyy") & " Daily Metrics"
    .HTMLBody = DaysRemain & " Remain in this month"
End With

MyEmail.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: Typo. d in quotes. `DaysRemain = VBA.DateDiff("d", Now(), EndDate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just one tiny change:

```
Public Sub MetricsMail()
Dim MyEmail As MailItem
Dim DaysRemain As Long
Dim EndDate As Date
EndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)
DaysRemain = Date()-EndDate

Set MyEmail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
With MyEmail
    .To = "Metrics"
    .Subject = Format(Now(), "mmmm dd, yyyy") & " Daily Metrics"
    .HTMLBody = DaysRemain & " Remain in this month"
End With

MyEmail.Display

End Sub
```

Have a nice weekend! Max

Comment: Sometimes seeing it a different way works. I flipped the order of EndDate and Date to get the sign correct, but other than that, code works.